# Javascript generate select list value not available in the next page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Below is code for a page to grab some user input and the SELECT List/Dropdown date are generated by the script mentioned in the code. Script works and populates the dropdown with date for next 90 dates based on current date.

Issue with this script is that i cant catch the value of this dropdown using PHP script as the "Select List is dynamically generate and is not visible in the HTML Source. I am not sure how to grab the value of ddDate dropdown in another page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>
$(function(){
    function pad(n){return n<10 ? '0'+n : n}
    var date = new Date();
    var selectElement = $('<select name="ddDate" class="ddDate" >'), optionElement;
    for (var count =0; count < 90; count++){
        formattedDate = pad(date.getUTCDate()) + '-' + pad(date.getUTCMonth()+1) + '-' +  date.getUTCFullYear();
        optionElement = $('<option>')
        optionElement.attr('value',formattedDate);
        optionElement.text(formattedDate);
        selectElement.append(optionElement);
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    $('#ddDate').append(selectElement);
});

function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["txtFN"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name is required");
  return false;
  }

  var y=document.forms["myForm"]["txtLN"].value;
if (y==null || y=="")
  {
  alert("Last name is required");
  return false;
  }

  var z=document.forms["myForm"]["txtEmail1"].value;
if (z==null || z=="")
  {
  alert("Email addres is required");
  return false;
  }

  var a=document.forms["myForm"]["txtEmail2"].value;
if (a==null || a=="")
  {
  alert("Confirm email is required");
  return false;
  }

  if (z != a)
  {
        alert("Email address don't match");
  return false;
  }

  var v=document.forms["myForm"]["txtVisitorNo"].value;
  if (v==null || v=="")
  {
  alert("Enter value number of visitors");
  return false;
  }

    var vv=document.forms["myForm"]["txtVisitorNo"].value;
  if (vv < 1)
  {
  alert("Enter valid number of visitors");
  return false;
  }



  return true;
}

</script>

</head>

<body >
<form name="myForm" action="bookingFormNext.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">

<table dir="ltr"  width="100%"height="760px" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"   valign="middle" background="Images/bg-img.gif" >

   <table  width="882"height="630" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
     <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <td width="203" align="left" valign="top"><img src="Images/LeftBarImage.png"            width="203" height="630" alt="" /></td>
        <td width="38" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="450" align="left" valign="top">

        <table width="100%" border="0">

          <tr>
            <td width="25%">&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="Title"><br />
              MOSQUE AND CENTRE</td>
            </tr>

          <tr>
            <td height="40px" colspan="4" class="TitleBlue">BOOKING FORM</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" height="25px" class="TextBlue">Fields marked with * are mandatory</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" height="5px" ></td>

            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="labels" >First Name:</td>
            <td colspan="3"><input name="txtFN" type="text" class="TextBox" id="txtFN" /> 
            &nbsp;*
              </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="labels">Last Name:</td>

            <td colspan="3"><input name="txtLN" type="text" class="TextBox" id="txtFN2" />
              &nbsp;* </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="labels">Email:</td>
            <td colspan="3"><input name="txtEmail1" type="text" class="TextBox" id="txtFN3" />
              &nbsp;* </td>

          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="labels">Confirm Email:</td>
            <td colspan="3"><input name="txtEmail2" type="text" class="TextBox" id="txtFN4" />
              &nbsp;* </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="labels">Country:</td>

            <td colspan="3">

<select class="ddCountry" id="ddCountries" name="ddCountries">
    <option value="" selected>Please Select a Country</option>
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>

    <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
    <option value="Angola">Angola</option>
    <option value="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
    <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
    <option value="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>

    <option value="Argentina">Argentina</option>
    <option value="Armenia">Armenia</option>
    <option value="Aruba">Aruba</option>
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>

    <option value="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
    <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
    <option value="Barbados">Barbados</option>
    <option value="Belarus">Belarus</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>

    <option value="Belize">Belize</option>
    <option value="Benin">Benin</option>
    <option value="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
    <option value="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
    <option value="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
    <option value="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>

    <option value="Botswana">Botswana</option>
    <option value="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
    <option value="Brazil">Brazil</option>
    <option value="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
    <option value="Brunei Darussalam">Brunei Darussalam</option>
    <option value="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>

    <option value="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
    <option value="Burundi">Burundi</option>
    <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
    <option value="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>

    <option value="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
    <option value="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
    <option value="Chad">Chad</option>
    <option value="Chile">Chile</option>
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>

    <option value="Cocos (Keeling) Islands">Cocos (Keeling) Islands</option>
    <option value="Colombia">Colombia</option>
    <option value="Comoros">Comoros</option>
    <option value="Congo">Congo</option>
    <option value="Congo, The Democratic Republic of The">Congo, The Democratic Republic of The</option>
    <option value="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>

    <option value="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
    <option value="Cote D'ivoire">Cote D'ivoire</option>
    <option value="Croatia">Croatia</option>
    <option value="Cuba">Cuba</option>
    <option value="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
    <option value="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>

    <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
    <option value="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
    <option value="Dominica">Dominica</option>
    <option value="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
    <option value="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
    <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>

    <option value="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
    <option value="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
    <option value="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
    <option value="Estonia">Estonia</option>
    <option value="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
    <option value="Falkland Islands (Malvinas)">Falkland Islands (Malvinas)</option>

    <option value="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
    <option value="Fiji">Fiji</option>
    <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
    <option value="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>

    <option value="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
    <option value="Gabon">Gabon</option>
    <option value="Gambia">Gambia</option>
    <option value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
    <option value="Ghana">Ghana</option>

    <option value="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
    <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
    <option value="Greenland">Greenland</option>
    <option value="Grenada">Grenada</option>
    <option value="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
    <option value="Guam">Guam</option>

    <option value="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
    <option value="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
    <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
    <option value="Guinea-bissau">Guinea-bissau</option>
    <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
    <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>

    <option value="Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands">Heard Island and Mcdonald Islands</option>
    <option value="Holy See (Vatican City State)">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
    <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
    <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
    <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
    <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>

    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
    <option value="Iran, Islamic Republic of">Iran, Islamic Republic of</option>
    <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
    <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
    <option value="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>

    <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
    <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
    <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
    <option value="Jersey">Jersey</option>
    <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>

    <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
    <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
    <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
    <option value="Korea, Democratic People's Republic of">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
    <option value="Korea, Republic of">Korea, Republic of</option>
    <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>

    <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
    <option value="Lao People's Democratic Republic">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
    <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
    <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
    <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
    <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>

    <option value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
    <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
    <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
    <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
    <option value="Macao">Macao</option>
    <option value="Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>

    <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
    <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
    <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
    <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
    <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
    <option value="Malta">Malta</option>

    <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
    <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
    <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
    <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
    <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
    <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>

    <option value="Micronesia, Federated States of">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
    <option value="Moldova, Republic of">Moldova, Republic of</option>
    <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
    <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
    <option value="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
    <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>

    <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
    <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
    <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
    <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
    <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
    <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>

    <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
    <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
    <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
    <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
    <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
    <option value="Niger">Niger</option>

    <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
    <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
    <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
    <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
    <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
    <option value="Oman">Oman</option>

    <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
    <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
    <option value="Palestinian Territory, Occupied">Palestinian Territory, Occupied</option>
    <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
    <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
    <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>

    <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
    <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
    <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
    <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
    <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
    <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>

    <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
    <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
    <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
    <option value="Russian Federation">Russian Federation</option>
    <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
    <option value="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option>

    <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
    <option value="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
    <option value="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
    <option value="Saint Vincent and The Grenadines">Saint Vincent and The Grenadines</option>
    <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
    <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>

    <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
    <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
    <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
    <option value="Serbia">Serbia</option>
    <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
    <option value="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>

    <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
    <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
    <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
    <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
    <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
    <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>

    <option value="South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and The South Sandwich Islands</option>
    <option value="Spain">Spain</option>
    <option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
    <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
    <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
    <option value="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>

    <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
    <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
    <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
    <option value="Syrian Arab Republic">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
    <option value="Taiwan, Province of China">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
    <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>

    <option value="Tanzania, United Republic of">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
    <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
    <option value="Timor-leste">Timor-leste</option>
    <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
    <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
    <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>

    <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
    <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
    <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
    <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
    <option value="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
    <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>

    <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
    <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
    <option value="United Arab Emirates" >United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="United States">United States</option>
    <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>

    <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
    <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
    <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
    <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
    <option value="Viet Nam">Viet Nam</option>
    <option value="Virgin Islands, British">Virgin Islands, British</option>

    <option value="Virgin Islands, U.S.">Virgin Islands, U.S.</option>
    <option value="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
    <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
    <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
    <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
    <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>

</select>
&nbsp;* </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="labels">Company:</td>
            <td colspan="3"><input name="txtCompany" type="text" class="TextBox" id="txtFN5" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="labels">Contact Number:</td>

            <td colspan="3"><input name="txtCC" type="text" class="TextBox50" id="txtFN7" />              <input name="txtContactNumber" type="text" class="TextBox170" id="txtFN6" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="labels">Number of Visitors:</td>
            <td colspan="3"><input name="txtVisitorNo" type="text" class="TextBox20" id="txtFN8" />
              &nbsp;* </td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" height="5px"></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td width="5%" height="50" valign="top"><input name="Subscribe" type="checkbox" class="chkBox" id="Subscribe" />
              <label for="Subscribe"></label></td>
            <td  valign="top" class="TextGreySmall" align="justify"></td>

            <td width="19%" valign="top" class="TextGreySmall">&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" class="labels">Please select the date and time of your tour:</td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" align="right" width="50%"><div id="ddDate"> </div></td>

            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
            <select name="ddTime" class="ddTime" id="ddTime">
            <option>09:00</option>
            <option>09:30</option>

            <option>10:00</option>
            <option>10:30</option>
            <option>11:00</option>
            <option>11:30</option>
            <option>12:00</option>
            <option>12:30</option>

            <option>13:00</option>
            <option>13:30</option>
            <option>14:00</option>
            <option>14:30</option>
            <option>15:00</option>
            <option>15:30</option>

            <option>16:00</option>
            <option>16:30</option>
            <option>17:00</option>
            <option>17:30</option>
            <option>18:00</option>
            <option>18:30</option>

            <option>19:00</option>
            <option>19:30</option>
            <option>20:00</option>

            </select>
            </td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td height="5px"></td>
            <td height="5px" colspan="2"></td>
            <td height="5px"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td ><input type="Reset" name="btnReset" class="btnGrey id="btnReset" value="Reset" /></td>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btnblue" value="Next >>">


            </td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="4" height="15px" >
</td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
        <td width="178" align="left" valign="top"><img src="Images/logo.png" width="133" height="118" alt="" /></td>

     </tr>
    </table>


    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Following code in PHP script is always empty

```
echo "Date : ". $_POST['ddDate'];
```

Is there a posibility that i can assign the ddDate onchange event to a hidden field so that it will be stored in hidden input text field.

Comment: Cannot reproduce (meaning: ddDate is filled just fine).

Comment: If all you're trying to do here is populate the select list with dates, you should really do that server-sided.

Comment: This should work just fime. Maybe your'e posting you for via GET? Try echoing out `$_REQUEST['ddDate']` and if that that doesn't help then try `var_dump($_REQUEST);` to see what is sent to your script.

Comment: @Connum Client side will just fine. I's even better for page load, cause javascript that generates is smaaler than php generated HTML and this can be cached.

Comment: @Kristian and with JS disabled, the whole booking process won't work! ;)

Comment: Usually js is not disabled. And if is, then not by regular dumbuser. But you have a point. Acutally that js could replace text what say that you need to enable js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is maybe that there is the `div` with the *id=ddDate* and the `select` with the *name=ddDate*. Try to give different id or name either to the div or the select element.